# Powershell connect to firebird

Tags: powershell, firebird

Hey I was wondering how one could connect to a firebird database (gdb) file from within powershell. Is there a way to use the .net data provider for firebird to connect? Is there a way to connect with System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection to firebird?

Answer (score 1):

```
function Get-ODBC-Data{
param([string]$query=$(throw 'query is required.'))
$conn=New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$connStr = "Driver={Red Database/Firebird driver};Server=localhost;Port=****;Database=*.fdb;Uid=user;Pwd=userpassword;"
$conn.ConnectionString= $connStr
$conn.open
$cmd=new-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query,$conn)
$cmd.CommandTimeout=15
$ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet
$da=New-Object system.Data.odbc.odbcDataAdapter($cmd)
[void]$da.fill($ds)
$ds.Tables[0] 
#Write-Output $ds.Tables[0].rows.count
$conn.close()
}

$query = @"
select count(*)
from UNIFO_PAYMENT U
join DOCUMENT D on D.ID = U.ID
"@

$result = Get-ODBC-Data -query $query
```

Comment: Please add some description of what you done in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The code from @Alexandr is from https://www.andersrodland.com/working-with-odbc-connections-in-powershell/

I suggest you read the entire thing. While he isn't exactly explaining the code either, I think it's fairly self-documenting, the only information that is missing, is how to get/use the Firebird driver.

You can get the ODBC driver installer from firebird https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/odbc-driver/

After Installing it, open windows ODBC administration (odbcad32.exe), check the drivers tab to make sure that the "Firebird/Interbase(r) driver" is there.

From here you can either use that driver name to run @Alexandr 's code

```
$connStr = "Driver=Firebird/Interbase(r) driver;Server=localhost;Port=****;Database=*.fdb;Uid=user;Pwd=userpassword;"
```

OR Go to either the User DSN tab, or the system DSN tab. Click add, select the firebird driver, set up the DSN with a name, the path to your database and the other required database registration info you normally would. Keep the DSN name simple, it's an identifier you will use.

Then you can simply replace the $constr with

```
$connStr = "DSN=YourDsnName;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, powershell allows you to create .Net classes and call .Net methods. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver2008r2trainingcourse_powershellv2fordevelopers_topic10). So with little trouble you can convert your C# code to powershell.