# Connection to firebird from powershell script

Tags: powershell, firebird

How can I connect to firebird database from powershell script (.ps1)?

Can someone provide me the code? I've tried with an SQL server and got no problem with that but I need to make a connection to firebird.

Your comments are heartily welcomed.

I've used InvokeQuery module

Code:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "****(mykey)" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("myuid", $password)
$db = "PDMconv_data.GDB"
$server = "89.105.195.151:D:\databases\PDMconv_data.GDB"
$query="select * from PGR010_GET_THE_ALGOPD;"
$result = Invoke-FirebirdQuery -Sql $query -Database $db -Server $server -Credential $mycreds -Verbose
$result | ft
```

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704610/powershell-connect-to-firebird

Comment: There isn't clear explanation in that post which is why i posted this issue

Comment: Then show what you tried and explain what you're stuck on.

Comment: `Can someone provide me the code` SO isn't a code writing service, if you contribute your own code we'll happily attempt to help you but you have to have a go at it yourself.

Comment: I've updated with code, thanks for your replies

Comment: I know next to nothing about Firebird, but are you sure about the `$server = "89.105.195.151:D:\databases\PDMconv_data.GDB"`? Combining IP address and path to a file with colon looks strange. Colon is often used to specify a TCP port, but what do I know?

Comment: As i am also a beginner, i doubt that too, but i've also tried only specifying 89.105.195.151

Comment: @vonPryz It depends on what is used to connect. The URL format a lot of native Firebird tools use is `<host>[/<port>]:<database>` because that is what is used by the fbclient.dll library. However non-native tools (eg for Java or C#) may use different formats.

Comment: What is this `Invoke-FirebirdQuery` you use? What exactly is wrong with this code?